# Вопрос про PHP (новичок). Почему не работает?

Tags: php

Нужно сделать проверку, чтобы входящий массив был кратен 3 значениям.
Сделал так:

```
$in = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
if (count($in) % 3 == 0){ // Проверяем массив, чтобы он был кратен 3
    $dvumer = array_chunk($in, 3); // делаем двумерный массив
    $result = array_map(foo, $dvumer); // для каждого куска массива применяем функцию
    print_r($result);
    function foo($kusok){
        $kusok = array_combine(['a', 'b', 'c'], $kusok);
        return $kusok;
    }
}
```

И это не работает. А если убрать if, то код работает на ура, но условие там задано верно и срабатывает(проверял меняя весь код на echo "123"), тогда почему не работает код, когда есть условие и работает стоит мне только удалить if?

Comment: вынесите объявление функции на верхний уровень и возьмите название функции в кавычки

Comment: Помогло! Помогло, когда я вынес функцию на верхний уровень. Но мне не понятно, почему это заработало, когда это и без вынесения вверх это очень хорошо работало вне условного оператора. И про кавычки я не понял =( Без них вроде заработало, но зачем брать название в кавычки и самое главное как? в эти - " " ? Тогда название функции превращается в string и выдает ошибку. И спасибо большое )) Особенно за такой оперативный ответ в 7 утра))

Comment: без кавычек `Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)` - включите вывод ошибок

Comment: `без вынесения вверх это очень хорошо` - функции, объявленные внутри условного блока, не существуют, пока код их определения не выполнен. А вот на верхнем уровне, они сразу становятся доступными

Comment: Премного благодарен Вам!

Comment: анонимная функция тут более органично впишется